# DataFactory git environment prod and dev, upload resource but not LinkedService and Trigger folder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure DataFactory resource and I want two environments (prod and dev), where dev and prod should have their own (different) LinkedService and Trigger.

When modified pipeline from branch "develop" git and save, I can't execute trigger because a message appears and it says something like that I should merge "develop" branch with "master" branch but I would like only to merge the pipeline and the dataset, for example, NO linkedservice and trigger.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?